# Dropdowns losing sync with data using angularjs in IE

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have created a dropdown which has a set of values as a default, and will be updated with a different set once a button is pressed. The problem is that the initially selected value of the new set isn't always using the same index as the previous set, and is instead selecting the first item of the new set even though the same value is present. (ex. March becomes January)

A second problem that is related to this is I have started the dropdowns with a null value, but once I click any value in the dropdown it sets the value automatically to the first item in the list.

These problems are only happening in Internet Explorer. I have tested it in 9, 10, and 11 with the problem occurring on all of them.

Related plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/eg7uclmKFTs2bU9xLYIm?p=info

Comment: ... what version if IE?

Comment: I have tested 9,10, and 11 so far with the problem on all of them.

Comment: So I tested it and you're correct. Seems to be a problem with IE and `ngOptions`. If you change the `select` to have an `<option>` tag inside with `ngRepeat` iterating over your months, your second problem is fixed. I have no idea how to solve the first one though.